# Force view to redraw after setting platform specific attributes

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have [the following hack](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/550#issuecomment-221194285) that draws drop shadows for the various elements that I have:

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <TabView>
            <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
                <StackLayout @loaded="addShadow">
                    <Label text="This box does have a shadow." />
                </StackLayout>
            </TabViewItem>
            <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label text="This box doesn't have a shadow." />
                </StackLayout>
            </TabViewItem>
        </TabView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            addShadow(event) {
                if (event.object.ios) {
                    event.object.ios.layer.masksToBounds = false;
                    event.object.ios.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
                    event.object.ios.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
                    event.object.ios.layer.shadowColor = new Color('#000000').ios.CGColor;
                    event.object.ios.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

StackLayout {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 16;
    margin: 16;
}

</style>
```

However, while the shadow looks perfect, it does not initially appear when the tab is first accessed. I have to first visit the second tab, and only after returning to the first tab, does the drop shadow get drawn.

I assume this is because I need to invoke something to redraw the layer after adding the shadow, but I cannot figure out how to do that. I've tried `event.object.ios.layer.setNeedsDisplay()` but it has no effect.

How can I ensure the shadow displays on the first tab render?

Comment: Why not add a conditional  CSS class to those tabs? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would work to solve my problem?